# Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]

Tags: elasticsearch

Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]

When I add a field to an existing index, there is a problem.

How to finish this at elasticsearch?

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I write this:

```
PUT my-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "content2": {
      "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you get when running `GET my-index`?

Comment: index is too long, you can see my answer.

Comment: Just tested this on 7.9 and that worked. Which version of ES are you running on?

Comment: elasticsearch 7.7.1

Comment: @Delispice `_all` field was deprecated in 6.0.0.